# Univariate analysis in logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic

I am doing multivariate analysis using logistic regression to see the relationship between one categorical outcome variable and a group of continuous and categorical explanatory variables. I did preliminary explanatory analysis using chi-square for the categorical covariates and t-tests and Mann-Whitney tests for the continuous variables based on the type of the distribution.

When I did the univariate analysis using binary logistic regression for the same variables, the results are different for the skewed data (previously analysed by Mann-Whitney) and the same for the normal data (previously analysed by t-test).

Should I stick to the logistic regression for the univariate analysis, or should I do either transformation or categorization for the skewed data before launching the multivariate analysis?

Comment: Why are you doing the univariate analysis? Is it for a table? Curiosity? Hypothesis test? Or what?

Comment: To add to Peter's questions, univariate analysis can cause an amazing amount of damage when done before multivariable analysis, because there is a temptation to use the uivariate results in guiding model building.

Comment: I am doing the univariate analysis to decide which variables be included in the model using the p value of 0.25 as a cut off point

Comment: When **not** used to decide on inclusion/exclusion of variables, it can be useful in understanding results.